# How to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is $T_1$?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I want to show directly that $\mathbb{R}$ is $T_1$, meaning that for any two points $x,y \in X$ there exists two open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x \in U$ and $y \notin U$, and  $y \in V$ and $x \notin V$.

I am aware that I just need to show that one-point sets are closed in $\mathbb{R}$ and my proof will be complete.

Will someone help me write a rigorous proof for this?

Comment: If you use the usual topology induced by the metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ (absolute value again defined casewise), all you need is that $U = B_{\frac12 d(x,y)}(x)$ and $V = B_{\frac12 d(x,y)}(y)$ are valid choices (both are open intervals centered around $x,y$ resp. with diameter $d(x,y)$)

Comment: If you have as a theorem from class that it is $T_2$, can you show that $T_2 \rightarrow T_1$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}, x\neq y$. Take $r<\frac{|x-y|}{2}$. Then you can take $U=B(x,r)$ and $V = B(y,r)$. This proves even more: $\mathbb{R}$ is $T_2$.

Comment: So I can say "Let x,y∈R,x≠y.  Choose r<|x−y|/2.  Then there exist open disjoint sets U=B(x,r) around x and V=B(y,r) around y.  Therefore there exist two open sets U and V such that x∈U and y∉U, and y∈V and x∉V.  R is T1."

Comment: ^ That's an fully rigorous proof, correct?

Comment: I wouldn't say `there exist' because you specify them explicitly but apart from that it is correct.

Comment: The proof is rigorous once there are no doubts left, which I believe is the case. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, ok.  I will replace "There exist" with "Then we can choose".  Yeah I see, thank you very much.